# How to get the InnerXml of matching text

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using C#.

I have an `XmlElement` with `InnerXml`

```
<b xpage="5" xid="85">3-6.  Title</b><i>. The Content</i>
```

which makes the `InnerText` as

**3-6.  Title***. The Content*

Now I have a match variable with value

```
3-6.  Title.
```

What i wanted to get is the rest of the portion of InnerXml ..ie.

```
<i> The Content</i>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Post the code you have so far, as well as a snippet of the actual XML.

Answer (score 0):

in the OuterXml property you get the xml string you want `<i>. The Content</i>`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<rootxml><b xpage=\"5\" xid=\"85\">3-6.  Title</b><i>. The Content</i></rootxml>");

XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

var completeString = root["b"].OuterXml + root["i"].OuterXml;
if (completeString.StartsWith("3-6.  Title.") {
  XmlElement xmlElement = root["i"];
  var iContent = xmlElement.OuterXml;
  Console.WriteLine(iContent);
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi punker76, The match value is "3-6.  Title." , not "3-6.  Title"  , So i'm not able to directly compare the value.

Comment: punker76, the match i.e "3-6.  Title." get generated at run time. The output of your code will give me <i>. The Content</i> where the output I'm looking for is <i> The Content</i>

Comment: then copy your nested part from the InnerXml without the point

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two sibling nodes, `B` and `I`. To match a specific instance of `B`, use an XPath text selector.

```
string xpath = "//*/b[text()='3-6.  Title']"; // replace wildcard with real path
```

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzxpathqueryexmp.htm

Once you have matched `B`, you can use the `NextSibling` property to find `I`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.nextsibling.aspx

Comment: Hi Tim, the problem is that i cant use XPath text selector with the match i have. Please notice that i have match as "3-6.  Title.", however the text of first child i.e B is "3-6.  Title".

Comment: If you are trying to match content across two nodes, you will have to examine both nodes either with a more complex XPath expression or by just looping through the nodes. Once you have a match, you will need to parse out the value of the I node (for example, to remove a leading period).

Comment: Right,match content spreads across two nodes. The problem is that the match is get generated by separate RegEx at run time.